# Reparameterization trick for other non-normal distributions? (Example tensorflow code?)

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, variational-bayes

Can anyone point me toward tensorflow code for the reparameterization trick for non-normal distributions? (uniform, beta, poisson, negative-binomial, etc?) Both for the sampling stage and the KL loss stage?

I am trying to understand and implement latent variables in tensorflow models. I roughly understand how the reparameterization trick works in principal, how it's implemented as a sampler, and included as a KL divergence in the loss. There are many, many, good examples online for the normal distribution and a few discrete distributions, but none that I can find for other distributions.

Normal examples (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py)

Gumbel example (http://blog.evjang.com/2016/11/tutorial-categorical-variational.html)

Further, has the expansion of tf.contrib.distributions made this easier recently? Many of the online examples are a few years old and write out the math fully for the sampling and loss, and I've read that they've made the sampling direction differentiable but I'm unclear on how.

Answer (score 1):

One way to roll out your own reparameterized multivariate distribution is to use the `Affine` bijector with `TrasformedDistribution`, eg,

```
ds = tf.contrib.distributions
ds.TransformedDistribution(
  distribution=ds.Gamma(...),  # or whatever
  bijector=ds.bijectors.Affine(...)
  event_shape=[dims])
```

As long as the distribution has no learned parameters or is itself reparameterized, the above is always a reparameterized distribution.